Inventory Management Challenge in POS
I'm currently working on a Laravel POS system for a liquor store, and I'm facing a challenge with inventory management. The store has various products with different packaging options, each with its own barcode. For instance:

Budweiser 500ml 12Pack (Barcode: 6003326011969) just example barcodes
Budweiser 500ml Can Case (Barcode: 6003326011952) just example barcodes
Budweiser 500ml loose can (Barcode: 6003326011945) just example barcodes

When customers purchase items, they might buy individual cans, cases, or packs. For example, a case might contain 4 packs of 6 cans each, or 2 packs of 12 cans each.
The issue arises during stock-taking. If, for instance, I remove a 12-pack from inventory to put in the fridge, I also need to deduct the quantity of loose cans accordingly. Similarly, if a promotion offers a case containing 24 cans, which is equivalent to 4 packs of 6 cans, I need to adjust the quantities of individual packs as well. they also can open a 12 pack and or sealed 6 pack and bring 1 or 2 loose items to the front of the store
Given that each packaging option has its own barcode, how can I implement a system in Laravel to ensure accurate inventory management, accounting for these relationships between different packaging options and their constituent products?
Currently, the system functions properly when individual items are added, but as I mentioned, there's a challenge regarding accurate stock management. I'm unfamiliar with how product variety operates, and I've been reading about it. Any assistance in understanding and implementing this feature would be greatly appreciated.
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('barcode')->nullable();
    $table->string('size')->nullable();
    $table->foreignId('department_id')->constrained('departments');
    $table->decimal('price', 10, 2)->nullable();
    $table->decimal('cost', 10, 2)->nullable();
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('quantity')->default(0);
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('security_stock')->default(3);
    $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();
    $table->string('number', 32)->unique();
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained('users');
    $table->decimal('subtotal', 12, 2)->nullable();
    $table->decimal('tax', 12, 2)->nullable();
    $table->decimal('total', 12, 2)->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});

class OrderItem extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'price',
        'quantity',
        'product_id',
        'order_id',
    ];

    public function product() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
    }

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Order::class);
    }
}

class Product extends Model {
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'old_price',
        'price',
        'cost',
        'quantity',
        'security_stock',
        'size',
        'department_id',
        'barcode',
    ];

    public function department() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
    }

    public function orderItems() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }
}

class Order extends Model {
    protected $fillable = [
        'number',
        'user_id',
        'subtotal',
        'tax',
        'total',
    ];

    public function items() {
        return $this->hasMany(OrderItem::class);
    }

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}


There are quite a few ways to resolve issues like this. Here are two: 1. Conversion: A case can be converted to packs, and a pack can be converted to cans. You can set up rules for this. Opening a case or a pack means activating such a rule. 2. Collections: Define a case or pack as a collection of packs or cans. So a product can be either a singular product, or it can be collection of multiple products. As you might notice, if you try to develop this, a collection is very similar to a conversion rule. I've used the second solution in one of the systems I've developed.

You may want to look at http://schema.org, specifically their Product and Offer schemas, for some ideas.
